# How can I make jQuery send an insecure AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, ssl

I am able to send insecure requests using Curl:

```
roroco@roroco-Zhaoyang-K49 ~/Dropbox/rbs/ro_sinatra $ curl https://localhost:23314?q=a -k
{"word":"a","us_phonetic":"美 [eɪ] ","us_phonetic_voice":null,"en_phonetic":"英 [eɪ] ","en_phonetic_voice":null,"na.":"一","n.":"英文字母表的第一字母；【乐】A音","art.":"冠以不定冠词主要表示类别","网络":"从；按；一个"}
```

When I attempt to send the same request using a jQuery AJAX request I get the following error in the Google Chrome Developer Tools console:

```
GET https://localhost:23314/?q=a net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

How can I make this insecure request work in Chrome and presumably in other browsers that throw this error as well?

Comment: Enable CORS on the server

Comment: @ExplosionPills I still get `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` even I set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in server response

Comment: This question had some serious grammatical issues, so I rewrote it to ensure that anyone answering this question is able to help you appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting a URL with secure http `https://localhost:23314?q=a` and you're  getting this error because the browser is considering that your SSL certificate is self-signed and Google Chrome blocks by default this kind of resource considering it unsecure.

You need to either configure SSL properly on your server using [Apache2 SSL on Windows](http://www.neilstuff.com/apache2-ssl-windows.html) so that you get a valid certificate for your localhost, or simply request your page over standard HTTP.

Comment: sorry, I use linux, and the server is not apache, it's only ruby test server, can i make everything work with change server response headers?

Comment: I don't think changing the response headers will have any effect, this is chrome behavior towards https...Are you sure you have SSL properly configured on your server for localhost? Besides, do you really need to use https on localhost, why can't you just call the same link http?

Comment: if I use ajax in chrome content script, if I'm in https://google.com, the http request will be blocked, it only allow use https request